# Checking if list item in another list returning false when punctation or symbols

Tags: python, list

I have a large file that contains a list that looks like e.g.

```
word_list =['word', 'charles', 'luciana', '<charles', '@', 'yes!']
```

I have a function to check items against this list:

```
def item_in_list(word):
    if any(word in item for items in word_list):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This works fine when checking e.g **True** is returned for:

```
item_in_list('charles')
item_in_list('luciana')
```

When i check where a symbol is included then it fails e.g.:

```
item_in_list('@')
item_in_list('<charles')
```

The debugging details are that I expected **True** to be returned and not **false**

Comment: What does the `list` contain you are referring to?

Comment: Also, try not to use reserved words in your code for variable names. Eg: `list`

Comment: Question needs debugging details.

Comment: Thanks for downgrading my post. An example of the list is there on the first code block.

Comment: assuming that `list` contains the words shown above as a list object, I don't see anything wrong except a typo in `any(word in item for items in list)`; `item` vs `items`, further the code works as expected if you fix the typo.

Comment: The list contains the words in the first code block. i'm checking against that list.,

Comment: An example of the list is there on the first code block. <-  A markdown block of text is not a list. Show the content of the `list` variable. Your question is impossible to answer without this information.

Comment: Seemed pretty obvious to me but I've amended to be more specific.

Comment: Also what is `word_in_vocab`, the same as `item_in_list`?

Comment: Yes, apologies amended.

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast what about the typo in `any(word in item for items in list)`; `item` vs `items`?

Comment: [your code does not do what you say it does](https://abload.de/img/unbenannt03j6s.png) (if you fix the typo items -> item).

Comment: `any(word in item for items in list); item vs items`. It was this. I couldn't see that at all. If you want to put that as an answer then i can accept.

Comment: You should have gotten a `NameError`, not `False` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that list contains the words shown above as a list object, I don't see anything wrong except a typo in `any(word in item for items in list)`; `item` vs `items`.

I tested the code locally and it works as expected if you fix the typo.

```
word_list =['word', 
            'charles',
            'luciana',
          ' <charles',
            '@',
            'yes!']

def item_in_list(word):
    if any(word in item for item in word_list):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(item_in_list('@'))
print(item_in_list('<charles'))
```

However, as others commented, you could just simplify it as:

```
def item_in_list(word):
    return word in word_list
```

**Important to add that the two implementations are not equivalent as @timgeb comments. The first one performs substring-search, the second one performs membership-test.**

Comment: Note that the two implementations are not equivalent. The first one performs substring-search, the second one performs membership-test.

Comment: Thanks for pointing @timgeb. I totally missed that. I'll update my answer to add that.

Comment: No problem. I'm not really sure whether OP needs the first or second version.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want:

```
word_list =['word', 'charles', 'luciana', '<charles', '@', 'yes!']

def item_in_list(word):
    if word in word_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or if you want it shorter:

```
def item_in_list(word):
    return True if word in word_list else False
```

Comment: This can be simplified to: 
`def item_in_list(word):
    return True if word in word_list else False`

Comment: Haha, was just typing that!

Comment: or just `return word in word_list` ...

Comment: Thanks. I'm still seeing issues but it seems to be with how I have compiled `word_list`